# ASP.NET MVC 5 and LightInject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, light-inject

I am trying to use LightInject with my current project but I keep getting a null value.  I have a web app in MVC 5 and a business tier attached with it.  I have installed the *LightInject.Mvc* and *LightInject.Web* in my web project.  I have installed the *LightInject.Mvc* in my business project.

In the business tier, I have a compositionRoot.cs file:

```
using LightInject;
using SimpleKB.Business.Commands;

namespace SimpleKB.Business
{
    public class CompositeRoot : ICompositionRoot
    {
        public void Compose(IServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
        {
            serviceRegistry.Register<IRegisterUserCommand, RegisterUserCommand>();
            serviceRegistry.Register<ICreateCategoryCommand, CreateCategoryCommand>();
            serviceRegistry.Register<IUpdateCategoryCommand, UpdateCategoryCommand>();
        }
    }
}
```

Next, in the web project, in the Global.asax.cs, I have the following in the app_start method:

```
var serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer();
serviceContainer.RegisterFrom<Business.CompositeRoot>();
serviceContainer.EnableMvc();
```

Finally, my controller code looks like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IRegisterUserCommand RegisterUserCommand { get; set; }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            RegisterUserCommand.Execute();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I basically get the null exception in the controller when the code is trying to use *RegisterUserCommand*.  I assumed that LightInject automatically injected code when an interface is encountered.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after looking at the code for LigtInject.Mvc project.  Basically, the code in my global.asax.cs should look like below:

```
var serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer();
serviceContainer.RegisterFrom<Business.CompositeRoot>();
serviceContainer.RegisterControllers();
serviceContainer.EnableMvc()
```